# Apache Ofbiz 17 as Windows or Linux service

Tags: ofbiz

With recent OFBiz server, there is no option available from Gradle command to run OFBiz as service in Windows or Linux. what is the procedure to run OFBiz as service.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows operating system, you use Java Service Wrapper.

https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/How+to+Run+OFBiz+as+Windows+Service+with+Java+Service+Wrapper

On Linux operating system,
(1) create Linux user for Ofbiz runtime process. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/How+to+run+OFBiz+as+a+Service

(2) Copy `rc.ofbiz` to `/etc/init.d`

```
cp /opt/ofbiz/tools/rc.ofbiz /etc/init.d/ofbiz
```

(3) Declare environment variables

(4) Set right chmod

```
chmod 700 /etc/init.d/ofbiz
```

(5) Start/Restart services
...

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/How+to+run+OFBiz+as+a+Service